# passing massage from injected js to background.js in chrome extesion

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a problem with passing data from injected js to background.js

injected js name "getDOM.js" and injected with this code in background.js

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "getDOM.js"})
});
```

i want to pass data from getDOM.js to background.js, so in background.js there is a function that will be ran when context menu clicked

this is the function in background.js :

```
function SetLinks(info, tab) {

    chrome.extension.sendMessage({greeting: "GetURL"},
            function (response) {
                tabURL = response.navURL;
                alert(tabURL);
            });
}
```

as you can see i tried to send a massage and want to get tabURL (this is just for test)

in getDOM.js file i've wrote this code :

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse)
{
    if( request.greeting === "GetURL" )
    {
            sendResponse( {navURL:'test'} );       
    }
});
```

so the navURL must be returned. but it not working

it works reverse, i mean if i was trying for sending request "from" getDOM.js it will work. it seams the request function should be in getDOM.js otherwise it will not work. please help me

I also tried it this way :

**background.js**

```
function SetLinks(info, tab) {
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "GetURL"}, function(response) {
            alert(response.navURL);
      });
      });  
}

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(SetLinks);

// Set up context menu tree at install time.
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  // Create one test item for each context type.
  var contexts = ["page","selection","link","editable","image","video",
                  "audio"];
    var context = contexts[1];
    var title = "test";
    var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context],
                                         "id": "context" + context});

});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "getDOM.js"})
});
```

**getDOM.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (request.greeting === "GetURL")
      sendResponse({navURL:'test'});
  });
```

but still not working

Comment: when/where do you fire your **SetLinks** function?  on menu click, you are injecting script with listener for message that will be send from BG script. When are you sending that message?

Comment: when clicking context menu SetLinks will be fired (its in background.js). that time the massage must be send to getDOM.js and it will respond with "test"

Comment: getDOM.js file is included fine, i tried with alert. i just want to know how to pass a data to background.js from getDOM.js (requested by background.js)

Comment: Note, `chrome.extension.sendMessage`/`chrome.extension.onMessage` **are deprecated**. Use `runtime` variants.

Comment: i tired replacing "extension" with "runtime", is this what you mean ? but still not working i don't receive any data from injected js

Comment: updated my question, see last part maybe you can help me that way

Comment: there is a race condition between your **SetLinks** function and injecting code into tab page. They are both fired at the same time, so that content script is still not injected when msg is dispatched. You need to put your *SetLinks** in callback of executeScript

Comment: i see that you edited your question while I was commenting. Now your msg is delayed by tabs.query, but still... proper way would be to pass it after the condition is satisfied (eg. when tab have your script)

Comment: Do **not** add solutions to questions. If you wish, you can post your solution (if it's sufficiently different from the one already given) as an **answer**. I'm rolling back your edit.

Comment: @Xan thanks again, i did this
i still have one problem : when content is dynamic (not specific "test"), every time it will alert previous data. imagine getDOM.js will pass selected text, with this code it will pas previous selected data. how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Sending a request from the extension/`background.js` to a content script that you need to specify which tab to send it to. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.

I created the sample code and tested it works with me as below:

**Background.js**:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "sample text", "contexts":["page"],
                                         "id": "ViewAlert"
        });
  function contextClicked(info, tab) {
  if (info.menuItemId == "ViewAlert" ) {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "GetURL"}, function(response) {
            alert(response.navURL);
      });
      });  
    } 
};
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(contextClicked);
```

**Content.js**:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (request.greeting === "GetURL")
      sendResponse({navURL:'test'});
  });
```

Also keep in mind to add `"permissions": ["contextMenus"...]` in your manifest.

Comment: chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        tab = tab.id;
        alert(tab);
    });

  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab, {greeting: "GetURL"}, function(response) {
   alert(response.navURL);
    });

i tried this on background.js, not woking

Comment: I added this code to my SetLinks function (will be ran by click on context menu)
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "GetURL"}, function(response) {
    alert(response.navURL);
  });
  });

and this code to my getDom.js file :

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (request.greeting === "GetURL")
      sendResponse({navURL:'test'});
  });

Comment: @MehdiNazari Hint: putting code in comments is generally useless.

Comment: @MehdiNazari I've updated the answer it should work as your hope now.

Comment: still not working. maybe there is difference between your Content.js and my getDOM.js. you know i had injected this script using chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "getDOM.js"}) in background.js (not my manifest).

Comment: @gui47 i have updated my question, see last part. its full code of background.js and getDOM.js. maybe you can help me this way. thank you

Comment: @MehdiNazari Why don't you specify it in the `content_scripts` field in the manifest file? This is indeed the correct way of declaring content scripts that should run on all pages that match a certain URL. (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration)

Comment: @gui47 i still have one problem : when content is dynamic (not specific "test"), every time it will alert previous data. imagine getDOM.js will pass selected text, with this code it will pas previous selected data. how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution

**background.js**

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "getDOM.js"})
});


chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab){
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "GetURL"}, function(response) {
            alert(response.navURL);
      });
      });
});
```

**getDOM.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (request.greeting === "GetURL")
      sendResponse({navURL:'test'});
  });
```

Comment: Your solution injects `getDOM.js` every time the context menu is invoked. This creates quite a chaos, and also it does not guarantee the execution will complete in time for the message. Read up on the `executeScript` function, it can be used to return a result without messaging.

Comment: @Xan can you give me more details ?

Comment: Not in here, no. Maybe make a new question.